# How long was Dr. Bashir's nap?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-q

In "Q-Less," Dr. Bashir meets the recently-arrived Vash in her quarters, and arranges to meet her for a meal. While posing as a Bajoran waiter, Q argues with the doctor, imploring him to stay away from Vash. Bashir then begins to walk away, Q mock yawns, and Bashir gets sleepy. So sleepy, in fact, that he needs to retire to his quarters posthaste to get some ZZZs.

Can it be known approximately how long his nap lasts? On a side note, it's nice that Q allowed Bashir to wake up after his departure, or set an "alarm" for the doctor. He could have been a jerk and caused Bashir to sleep until the start of Season 5.

Comment: Re: Remembering to wake Bashir - Q may be many things but we've never seen him be *mindlessly* cruel.

Comment: He didn't seem to care about eighteen members of the *Enterprise* being killed or assimilated by the Borg. Also, I wish there were a Q-Odo scene. How could the writers not have these two iconic characters interact? It would have been something if Q had made Odo yawn and sleep like a human!

Comment: He didn't kill them. The Borg killed them. And the net result was that the Federation wasn't assimilated, saving trillions of lives.

Answer (score 6):

### Approximately 24 hours

Vash comes on board at the start of the first day, has a medical with Bashir and heads over to the assay office. Quark approaches her and she agrees to auction some of her items. Bashir invites her for dinner and en route Q tells him that he's feeling sleepy at which point Bashir exits stage left.

Later the following day (note the stage direction in [the script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/407.txt)) the auction takes place and Vash and Q leave the station. Bashir turns up again.

> 40   INT.  THE PROMENADE **(DAY TWO)**
>
> A humanoid alien (KOLOS) emerges from the airlock near Quark's.  He is
>   followed closely by a jewel-bedecked Ferengi. The Ferengi gazes warily
>   at his surroundings. He spots Kolos. The two aliens exchange hostile
>   glances as they walk the Promenade.